# Working Around SQL Replace Wildcards

Tags: mysql, replace, wildcard

I know that I cannot use a wildcard in a MySQL replace query through phpMyAdmin. But, I need some kind of workaround. I'm very open to ideas. Here's the skinny:

I have about 2,000 pages in a MySQL database that need to have image URL's updated. Some are local, some are hotlinked. Each one is different, the URL lengths vary, the image on the page and the new image are unique per page id number, and each one occurs at a different spot in the page.

I basically need to do the following:

```
UPDATE pages SET body = replace(body, 'src=\"%\"', 'src=\"http://newdomain/newimage.jpg\"') WHERE id="{page_number}"
```

But I know that the `'src=\"%\"'` component doesn't jive.

So I fall at the feet of your collective knowledge to come up with some way to take the `src="%"` and replace it with a set URL for a set page id number. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any sort of table that relates the old and new `src` values to the page id?

Comment: Yes and no. I have an Excel sheet with the new image URL and the page ID number. Ex., "image5.jpg" matches with page ID 123. The new ones are all in the same directory, so it'll end up being "mysite/images/image5.jpg" matched with page ID 123. I do NOT have a list of the old ones, though.

Comment: How do you propose to replace the old ones if you don't know what the values are? Is there only one image per page top be replaced or do certain new images need to replace certain old ones?

Comment: I know right? Hence the failed attempt at the wildcard....

Comment: Is there a way to structure a query to just get the src="..." text returned? The I could build that list since I know the page numbers. I keep getting the whole page, which can be upwards of a few thousand words each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one image per page, a quick solution would be like this:

```
UPDATE pages
SET
  body = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, 'src="', 1),
    'src=\"http://newdomain/newimage.jpg\"',
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, 'src="', -1)
      FROM LOCATE('"', SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, 'src="', -1))+1)
    )
WHERE
  id="{page_number}" AND
  body NOT LIKE '%<img%<img%';
```

First SUBSTRING_INDEX extract the body part at the left of `src="`, the last two nested SUBSTRING_INDEX extracts the body part at the right of the first `"` next to `src="`.

Last check is a very dirty check to make sure that only one image is present in the string. It could fail under some circumstances, but it might help.

Comment: This went through, but deleted everything after the image and left me with a blank page. Maybe the first SUBSTRING_INDEX isn't stopping at the second double quote?

Comment: @ShannonHollingsworth updated my answer, please see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e99b5/1 ... it doesn't look really nice, but it should be okay

Comment: That worked! :) I can use Excel to concatenate the images and page id's with this code in between. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to build a table with your replace strings that would look like this:

```
page_id     replace
1           src="..."
```

Then you can update across a JOIN like this

```
UPDATE pages AS p
INNER JOIN replace AS r
  ON p.page_id = r.page_id
SET p.body = REPLACE(p.body, CONCAT('src="', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.body, 'src="', -1), '"', 1), '"', r.replace);
```

This would replace the last occurrence anything of format `src="..."` with a new value in same format, so this would work for all records with a single src value.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I don't know what goes in the 'find' column. i do not have a list of URLs that already exist on the pages. I just have a list of new ones. :/

Comment: Is there only one URL per page to be replaced?

Comment: In most cases, yes. There are maybe 50 pages with multiple images.

Comment: @ShannonHollingsworth I have updated my answer with a way to solve those cases where there is just a single URL or multiple references to the same URL within a record.  If you know in advance the records with multiple URL's you could exclude them from the replace table

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4